# Creating a class with unordered map asymptotics in Python

Tags: python

The problem is to create a class in Python with unordered map asymptotics, and equiprobable one of the input elements.

So my code is

```
import random

class UnorderedMap:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}

  def insert(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value

  def remove(self, key):
    del self.data[key]

  def get_random_element(self):
    return random.choice(list(self.data.values()))
```

But apparently random.choice(list(self.data.values()))
is not an asymptotic unordered map, it should be O(1), but isn't mine O(1)? Apparently, making the *list* is already O(N). And list(self.data.values()) is N operations, sort of.

Comment: What do you mean by "unordered map asymptotics"?  (Did you mean "semantics" instead of "asymptotics"?) `random.choice` itself is not O(1), and having to build a list of `n` values just to create the *argument* for `random.choice` doesn't change that.

Comment: Unless you can pick a key in O(1) time, you can't get a value in O(1) time. One option would be to maintain a separate *list* of the values; then you could generate a random index `i` and use that to get an value from the list.

Comment: Yeah, "equivocating" is typo. I mean "equiprobable"

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of the keys that you can pass to `random.choice()`.

```
class UnorderedMap:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}
    self.keys = []

  def insert(self, key, value):
    if key not in self.keys:
        self.keys.append(key)
    self.data[key] = value

  def remove(self, key):
    del self.data[key]
    self.keys.remove(key)

  def get_random_element(self):
    return self.data[random.choice(self.keys)]
```

The only problem is that `remove()` is now O(N)

Comment: So how to make it O(1)? Not O(N)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make all the dict-like operations O(1) and also make randomization O(1). At some point you have to create a list to pass to `random.choice()`